# 400 (Bad Request) : Json object with an array of object

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring, hibernate

I have built an application using, `java`, `spring`, `hibernate` and `angular-js` at core. While on contraty `com.fasterxml.jackson` annotations for `json` parsing. The application is working fine i.e. when i send a call to my controller for saving an object of Event, my server assist it only if the object has empty array of another object(i.e Artists). Else if the array of object is populated in the sent object, the server throws bad request error yet no abnormality in logs.

**Event.class**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Event implements Serializable {

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private int id;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String title;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String type;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String dateTime;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String status;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String logo;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String videoThumbnail;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String detail;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private Artists[] artists;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String region;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String location;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String adUrl;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String videoUrl;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String interstitialUr;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String prerollUr;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String mediaType;


    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /**
     * @return the title
     */
...
```

**Artist.class**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Artists implements Serializable{

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private int id;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String title;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String image;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String detail;




    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /**
     * @return the title
     */
...
```

**Controller method**

```
@JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "save/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Event> saveEvent(@RequestBody Event event) {
        try{
            Event d_event = event;
            com.ceelive.dao.model.Event m_event = beanUtil.copyEventBeanDomainToModel(d_event);
            eventService.save(m_event);
            return new ResponseEntity<Event>(HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch(Exception exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity<Event>(HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
        }

    }
```

**Angularjs post call**

```
createEvent : function(event) {
                    var  url = $window.location.origin;
                    if(url.match('localhost')){
                        url = $window.location.origin+'/ceelive/events/save/'
                    } else {
                        url = url = $window.location.origin+'/events/save/' 
                    }
                    return $http.post(url, event)
                            .then(function(response) {
                                return response;
                            }, function(errResponse) {
                                console.error('Error while creating user');
                                return $q.reject(errResponse);
                            });
                },
```

[image: image is attached for json object structure]

Comment: What is the complete stack trace of the exception? Note that the JSON artist object has an array of events, that the Java class doesn't have.

Comment: @JB Nizet: If there were any exception or abnormality in logs at server side, i would have definitely share or try to resolve on the basis of it. Though logs are totally clear.

Comment: @Jb Nizet: I edited my answer. I didn't noticed that array of events in my json. I have added the events array in my java class, and it is working all fine now. Thanks a lot for your support fellow member. Be blessed.